# How to cause permutation event by manipulating ObservableList?

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

[`ObservableList`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/collections/ObservableList.html) listeners can receive [`Change`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) events with permutation set.

Simultaneously, among list operations, I see only ones to delete or insert elements.

Is it possible to perform such operation on list, which will cause permutation reported?

**UPDATE**

Here is the clarification code:

```
public class ObservableListPermutation {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


      list.add("timbuktu");
      list.add("timid");

      list.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
         @Override
         public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> c) {
            while(c.next()) {
               if( c.wasPermutated() ) {
                  System.out.println("Was permutated");
               }
            }
         }
      });

      System.out.println("Sorting by library:");
      Collections.sort(list);

      System.out.println("Sorting by own:");
      Collections2.sort(list);


   }


   public static class Collections2 {
      public static void sort(List<String> list) {
         String element = list.remove(0);
         list.add(element);
      }
   }
}
```

As you see, my custom permutation does not cause permutation event, because it is done by removing and adding elements. How to implement custom permutation, so that it cause permutation event?

**UPDATE 2**

If I try to trace `sort()` with debugger, I am unable to enter the code of `sort()`.

Comment: The simplest permutation that come to me would be sorting of List elements.

Comment: Or shuffle would cause these events, too, I guess: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-

Comment: Suppose I would like to write my own version of shuffle. If I use `remove()` and `add()` inside it, I would never cause permutation.

Comment: For the comment in "Update 2", if you are trying to figure out what `Collections.sort(list))` does, it simply invokes `list.sort(null)` (see [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u40/jdk/file/c7bbaa04eaa8/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java)). The list that is returned from `FXCollections.observableArrayList()` is an  instance of (non-public API) [`ObservableListWrapper`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/collections/ObservableSequentialListWrapper.java), which overrides `sort()` to manage events nicely.

Answer (score 3):

A very simple operation a List to report Permutation would be to sort the items in the List.

For example, the following code would print `true`.

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;

import java.util.Collections;

public class PermutationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObservableList<String> list = 
                         FXCollections.observableArrayList("Z", "Y", "X");
        list.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> c) {
                c.next();
                System.out.println(c.wasPermutated());
            }
        });
        Collections.sort(list);
    }
}
```

---

Answers to additional question :

> I would like to cause it myself, without calling black box methods. Suppose I have instance of ObservableList and nothing more and would like to code some manipulation, which causes permutation, How would I do this?

This is not possible if you are using the *ObservableList provided by FXCollections* util class because of the way ObservableList is implemented in it.

Considering the following points :

- Whenever you add or remove elements a [MappingChange](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/collections/MappingChange.java) is triggered.
- [ListChangeListener#wasPermutated()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/base/src/main/java/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.java#l174) checks if length of the int array returned by `getPermutation()` is greater than zero.
- In case of MappingChange, the [getPermuatation()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/collections/MappingChange.java#l96) always returns an int of length 0.

Now, you must be wondering (like I was), how does it work when we do a *sort* on the same List?

It turns out the [ObservableListWrapper](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/collections/ObservableListWrapper.java) (which is the base for creating list in FXCollections) overrides [sort()](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/collections/ObservableListWrapper.java#l211) and then forces a [SimplePermutationChange](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/base/src/main/java/com/sun/javafx/collections/NonIterableChange.java#l160).

> Is there an alternative?

You can create your own custom ObservableList by extending [ModifiableObservableListBase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ModifiableObservableListBase.html) as stated by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38914933/how-to-cause-permutation-event-by-manipulating-observablelist#comment65190038_38915181) and shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38918795/1759128).

Comment: So, how `sort()` could cause these events?

Comment: When you sort an ObservableList, a change takes place to arrange the elements in the List. This triggers a notification to ListChangeListener.

Comment: I would like to cause it myself, without calling black box methods. Suppose I have instance of `ObservableList` and nothing more and would like to code some manipulation, which causes permutation, How would I do this?

Comment: In general `FXCollections.sort` should be prefered to `Collections.sort`, but here it doesn't make a difference... @Dims Causing the event yourself is a bit tricky, since in most cases the firing of those events is taken care of automatically. The best option for doing it yourself is to extend [`ModifiableObservableListBase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ModifiableObservableListBase.html) and triggering the events manually.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on @ItachiUchiha's answer and @fabian's comment, any single operation that modifies an `ObservableList` will notify change listeners. So there is no way to trigger a "permutation event" on an `ObservableList` by calling a sequence of operations that each modify the list (each operation would notify listeners independently).

So to support permutations that are not supported out of the box (i.e. by [`FXCollections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#sort-javafx.collections.ObservableList-), [`FXCollections.shuffle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#shuffle-javafx.collections.ObservableList-), [`FXCollections.rotate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#rotate-javafx.collections.ObservableList-int-), and [`FXCollections.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#reverse-javafx.collections.ObservableList-)), you need to implement your own `ObservableList`, defining (or possibly overriding) single entry-point methods that trigger a permutation. The [`ModifiableObservableListBase` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ModifiableObservableListBase.html) provides a convenient starting point.

Here is a simple example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase;

public class PermutatingObservableList<E> extends ModifiableObservableListBase<E> {


    private final List<E> source ;

    public PermutatingObservableList(List<E> source) {
        this.source = source ;
    }

    public void permute(int[] permutation) {
        checkPermutation(permutation);
        beginChange();
        List<E> temp = new ArrayList<>(source);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < size() ; i++) {
            source.set(i, temp.get(permutation[i]));
        }
        nextPermutation(0, size(), permutation);
        endChange();
    }

    public void pairwiseSwap() {
        int[] permutation = new int[size()];
        for (int i = 0; i+1 < permutation.length ; i+=2) {
            permutation[i] = i+1 ;
            permutation[i+1] = i ;
        }
        if (permutation.length % 2 == 1) {
            permutation[permutation.length - 1] = permutation.length - 1 ;
        }
        permute(permutation);
    }

    private void checkPermutation(int[] permutation) {
        boolean valid = permutation.length == size();
        Set<Integer> values = IntStream.range(0, size()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        for (int i=0; i<permutation.length && valid ; i++) {
            valid = values.remove(new Integer(permutation[i]));
        }
        if (! valid) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid permuation: "+Arrays.toString(permutation)+"\n"
                    +"Permutation must be same length as list and must contain each of the values "
                    + "0-"+(size()-1)+" exactly once");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        return source.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return source.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdd(int index, E element) {
        source.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected E doSet(int index, E element) {
        return source.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected E doRemove(int index) {
        return source.remove(index);
    }

}
```

and a test:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;

public class PermutingObservableListTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> numbers = Arrays.asList("One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five");
        PermutatingObservableList<String> list = new PermutatingObservableList<>(new ArrayList<>(numbers));
        list.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(Change<? extends String> c) {
                while (c.next())
                    System.out.println(c.wasPermutated());
                    System.out.println(IntStream.range(0, list.size())
                        .map(c::getPermutation)
                        .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
                }
            }
        });

        list.pairwiseSwap();

        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

which produces the output

```
true
1, 0, 3, 2, 4
[Two, One, Four, Three, Five]
```